# Adding CSS to a checkbox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I am a bit of a newbie in .NET so apologies if this is a bit of a silly question.

I am trying create a cool checkbox using server-side checkboxes as opposed to the input=checkbox tags:

```
<div runat="server" id="divCheckBoxContainer" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;" class="divCheckBoxContainer">
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" />
  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" Width="100%" Height="18px" />
</div>
```

I have set the label to Visible=false because, in the code-behind, I have set whatever to be in the label to be an attribute for the ASP checkbox 
when I use the app control:

```
<uc2:CheckBox runat="server" LabelWidth="450" Width="50" IsAlternatingRow="false" ID="TEST" Label="TEST TEST" />
```

Comment: By "server side checkbox" do you mean a custom control?

Comment: yeah its a custom control

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own attributes to the control in the fashion of

```
<ARB:AccessibleCheckbox ID="cstmCB1" Text="Tick for yes" ContainerCssClass="myTB" TabIndex="0" runat="server"></ARB:AccessibleCheckbox>
```

and refer to value of the attribute in the code-behind with something like

```vb
<Bindable(True), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(""), Localizable(True)>
Property ContainerCssClass() As String
    Get
        Dim s As String = CStr(ViewState("ContainerCssClass"))
        If s Is Nothing Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return s
        End If
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        ViewState("ContainerCssClass") = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

You could then use it when rendering the control, say,

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)

    Dim currIndent = writer.Indent

    writer.BeginRender()

    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, Me.ContainerCssClass)
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
    ' (rest of code here)
```